# Missing chrome extension in launcher

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been using the chrome extension called POSTMAN for a little while and wanted to make some changes to it. The developer has helpfully provided the source on https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension

The "tool" is available in two forms :

An extension here : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

A packaged app here : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

I am having problems when I try to install these locally (as I would need to do when I change and test them).

In chrome I go to chrome://extensions/ and "Load Unpacked Extensions" one for each of the above as both are in the source from https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension

Both seem to load OK without any obvious errors and I can see them in the extensions list on 
chrome://extensions/

The "extension" version works fine and is visible in the "Chrome App Launcher" however the packaged app version does not show in the "Chrome App Launcher" even though it does show in chrome://extensions/

Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: Most probably it is th other way around: The extension is **not** showing in the "Chrome App Launcher" (which as its name suggests is for **apps** not **extensions**) and the app version **is** showing in the "Chrome App Launcher" (as it should).

Comment: I dont think that's the problem. When using the two original versions from the "Chrome Store" then both versions appear in the "Launcher" from the chrome browser or directly from windows. Both versions have different names so it easy do differentiate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one you refer to as "extension" is **not** an extension, but a **[Chrome App](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)**. Chrome Apps (in contrast to Chrome Extensions) show up in the "Chrome App Launcher", so nothing weird there.

The one you refer to as "packaged app" is indeed a **[Packaged App](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html)**, which is **not** a **[Chrome App](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)**, but a legacy form of app.

At the GitHus repo you menton, there are:

1. The source code for the Chrome App (not the "Packaged App"): https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/tree/master/chrome
2. The source code for a Chrome Extension (this is different from both links to the WebStore you provide): https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/tree/master/launcher

---

So, in WebStore there are :

1. A legacy "Packaged App" (shows in launcher).
2. A "modern" Chrome App (shows in launcher).

In repo there are:

1. The source code for a "modern" Chrome App (shows in launcher).
2. The source code for a "Chrome Extension" (does not show in launcher (nor should it)).

Comment: That's great, thanks for taking the time to give such a comprehensive answer. Looks like I've not got access to the source I thought I had.

Comment: Just for completeness the developer does publish the source for the "Chrome Extension" is's in one of the branches on GitHub

Comment: You mean the Packaged App ?

Comment: Yes - my mistake, again :-)